# Ошибки shellapi

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить данные ошибки? Они при всех действиях

Comment: Использовать "широкие" строки...

Comment: А можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

Использовать вместо `const char *` тип `const wchar_t *`. Например:

```
const wchar_t * sz = L"Hi";
```